# Unity Parse Push Can't Register Devices with iOS 9.1, Unity 4.6.9, and Parse 1.6.1

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I've spent a day trying to get push notifications to work with the Parse Unity SDK for an iOS app.

I followed the iOS push notifications tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

I've also used the Quick Start App provided by Parse for Push Notifications: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/unity/ios/new

But still the device will not show up.

I've already searched this forum but I can't find an answer for it.

And yes I've read the Troubleshooting guide mentioned in the guide.

When I run the app on my phone it does ask for permission to allow push notifications so it seems to be somewhat working.

But Parse will not pick up the device so I can't send notifications

But with any test app I make it will not register the apps. Here is also the code that I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;
using System;

public class PushBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
  // Use this for initialization
  void Awake() {
#if UNITY_IOS
    NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(RemoteNotificationType.Alert |
                                                            RemoteNotificationType.Badge |
                                                            RemoteNotificationType.Sound);

    var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
    installation.Channels = new List<string> { "ParseTest" };
    installation.SaveAsync();
#endif

    ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (sender, args) => {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
      AndroidJavaClass parseUnityHelper = new AndroidJavaClass("com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper");
      AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
      AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

      // Call default behavior.
      parseUnityHelper.CallStatic("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.StringPayload);
#elif UNITY_IOS
      IDictionary<string, object> payload = args.Payload;

      foreach (var key in payload.Keys) {
        Debug.Log("Payload: " + key + ": " + payload[key]);
      }
#endif
    };
  }
}
```

Any feedback as to where I am going wrong would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve it, but

```
NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes is deprecated.
```

Try using this instead.

```
UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications (UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Alert | UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Badge | UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType.Sound);
```

Comment: What version is this for? Unity 5? I am using Unity 4.6 and it does not have UnityEngine.iOS